# How to show a hidden div using jQuery if 3 input text fields in another div are not empty?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is hidden when the DOM is loaded, using hide().

```
    <div class="disappear">
    Some text appears here
    </div>
```

How do I make the above div (**.disappear**) show when the input fields with class **.master** (one to three) are not empty. (Ideally, trigger it on .blur in each of the input fields.)

```
    <div id="form">
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="one" class="master">
    <input type="text" name="two" class="master">
    <input type="text" name="three" class="master">
    <input type="text" name="four" class="slave">
    <input type="text" name="five" class="slave">
    </form>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, I think:

```
$('.master').change(function() {
    if ($('.master').filter(function() {
        return !this.value;
    }).length) {
        // some are empty
        $('.disappear').hide();
    } else {
        // none are empty
        $('.disappear').show();
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9R89/1/). Note that I've used `change` rather than `blur`, because it's semantically what you mean and it's going to be faster.

Comment: @Stroller Glad to help. If an answer has resolved your question, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: There seems to be a 5-minute gap before I can mark it as accepted. Will do as soon as it expires.

Answer (score 1):

You would be doing it inside some event handler.

```
function YourEventHandler()
{
  var v1=$.trim($("#one").val());
  var v2=$.trim($("#two").val());
  var v3=$.trim($("#three").val());
  if(v1 !== '' && v1 !== undefined && v2 !== '' && v2 !== undefined v3 !== '' && v3 !== undefined)
  $(".disappear").show();
  else $(".disappear").hide();
}
```

I haven't used the .master as you might have that class in other elements.
If not you can use that too.
Give it a try & let me know.

Answer (score 1):

try this ( this will also check for **emptyness** )

```
$('input.master').live('blur change', function () {
    var trimVal = $.trim($(this).val());
    if(!trimVal.length)
    {
        $('.disappear').show();
    }
    else {
         $('.disappear').hide();
    }   
});
```

### [working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/MSsmv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This jsfiddle should do the job http://jsfiddle.net/dxpbT/

```
$(".master").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        var $all = $('.master');
        var $empty = $all.filter('[value=""]');

        if ($empty.length == 0) {
            $(".disappear").show();
        }    
    }

});
```